# URL rewriting to create pretty with Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Suppose i have a URL that has many parameters and the url parameters  changes on every new request

`http://example.com/private.php?s=[HASH]&a=[SOMETHING]......`

I want the page  to show as `http://example.com/` to the user without affecting the script itself(i.e fetching of GET parameters should work).

The reason why i want to do this  is because the URL is unique to every user so if the user shares the URL above , it will ultimately redirect to homepage.URL being shown as `http://example.com/` will prevent users from sharing the wrong url and thus it will be better for seo purposes as well as for performance.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about the use for URL-rewriting, all the information needs to be in the URL in some way that the server can translate/rewrite into something the backend can understand. See: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/
To actually remove the information you need to either use "POST" or some kind of indirection on the page, eg. AJAX, you could also put any common information in the URL and have an identifier among the parameters so the backend can ignore those when needed.

Comment: You could store all of this information in some sort of server side session once the user visits a page.  (See PHP's $_SESSION if you're using PHP.)